# How to add an Enterprise Keywords column to a custom list?

Tags: custom-list, list-definition, enterprise-keywords

I have a custom solution that includes

1. Site Columns
2. List item
3. Content Types
4. List Definition
5. List Instance(Both List &
   Document Library)

Now I want to include a column of type "Enterprise Keywords" to allow the users to Tag.

How do I add the "Enterprise Keywords column" into the List Definition and create a List Instance.

Comment: Have you added the column to the content type definition?

Comment: https://egilhansen.com/2013/03/09/how-to-add-an-enterprise-keywords-column-to-a-custom-list-and-enable-keyword-synchronization-in-sharepoint-2013/